# Is there a way to check if your breaker box is grounded?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, grounding

I've got an old home, built in 1945. I assume the electrical box in the basement isn't that old. There's a ground to the main water line entry. There's also this other wire that looks like a ground following the supply line to the building exterior. Unfortunately, I'm not seeing this ground wire come out of the building when outside.

All of this is leading me to wonder if my electrical panel/ breaker box is grounded. Is there a way to test if your home is grounded, and not just the individual outlets?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does that "supply line" head directly to a box with only a meter in it, or does the box on the outside of the house with the meter in it have breakers in it too?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, the outside meter is only a meter, no breakers

Comment: Here in old blighty an electrican would use a loop impedance tester (generally offered as one of the functions on their multifunction tester) for this sort of thing, but I don't know if those are a think in america.

Answer (score 2):

Dig (carefully and gently so you don't damage the wire) it probably goes down into the ground where the service wire goes up along the wall. Grounding rods are commonly buried a bit at the top so they are not a tripping hazard, so the grounding conductor runs underground to them.

Comment: That's correct, this is concrete. I can't really dig.

Answer (score 2):

Since, per comment on @Ecnerwal's answer, you can't dig to find the ground rods, if there are any, you may have to get an electrician out to do a ground resistance test. This will tell not only *if* you're grounded but *how well* you're grounded, so safety upgrades can be planned if needed.